# Как создать статичный массив объектов?

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп, конструктор

Здравствуйте, мне для лабораторний нужно сделать массив из 5 статичных и 5 динамичных объектов класса, но при создании выскакивает ошибка: Class has more than one default constructor.
Так как у меня 3 конструктора:

```
Employee(string Name = " ", int Age = 1, int Salary = 1, int Experience = 1);
        Employee();
    Employee(const Employee &Sclass);
```

Вот функция создания массивов:

```
    void DemonstrationM()
    {
        Employee *membersD, membersP[5];
        try
        {

            membersD = new Employee[5];
        }
        catch (bad_alloc xa)
        {
            cout << "Не удалось добавить в дим. масив " << endl;
            system("Pause");
        }
for (int i = 0; i < Members.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (i < 5)
            membersD[i] = Members[i];
        else
        {
            membersP[i - 5] = Members[i];

        }
    }

    cout << membersP[2].getAge(1) << endl;
    cout << membersD[3].getAge(1) << endl;
    main();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас эти два конструктора

```
Employee(string Name = " ", int Age = 1, int Salary = 1, int Experience = 1);
Employee();
```

являются конструкторами по умолчанию, так как каждый из них может быть вызван без аргументов. А при объявлении массивов у вас используется как раз конструктор по умолчанию. Поэтому возникает неоднозначность. Компилятор не знает, какой из этих двух конструкторов вызвать при создании элементов массивов.

Уберите аргумент по умолчанию у первого параметра. Например

```
Employee( const std::string &Name, int Age = 1, int Salary = 1, int Experience = 1);
```

Можете его объявить также со спецификатором функции `explicit`, чтобы избежать неявных преобразований. Например,

```
explicit Employee( const std::string &Name, int Age = 1, int Salary = 1, int Experience = 1);
```

Имейте в виду, что вы не можете в программе на C++ рекурсивно вызывать функцию main. Это можно делать лишь в C. Поэтому этот код неверный

```
    //...
    cout << membersP[2].getAge(1) << endl;
    cout << membersD[3].getAge(1) << endl;
    main();
    ^^^^^^^
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не касаясь всего прочего, только почему ругань:

```
Employee(string Name = " ", int Age = 1, int Salary = 1, int Experience = 1);
Employee();
```

Вот тут, например

```
membersD = new Employee[5];
```

компилятор просто не знает, какой из них выбрать! Весь первый эквивалентен второму - при вызове без аргументов!

И еще - не передавайте в `catch` исключение по значению, лучше это делать по ссылке.